# Getting aplication/json params with post

Tags: json, slim

I'm using https://github.com/sahat/satellizer to login. 
It sends requests with header Content-Type:application/json (body with json ex:{login:login, password:pass})

On server side I use Slim Framework.
In order to retrive sent values I'm getting it through BODY

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\ContentTypes());

$app->post('/auth/login', function () use ($app) {
    $params = $app->request()->getBody();
    print_r($params);//I've got it
});
```

Can I retrive those params through post?

```
if ($app->request()->isPost()) {
        $email = $app->request->post('email');
        $password = $app->request->post('password');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is meant for form data. As you noticed you can can find JSON in request body instead.

```
$app->post('/auth/login', function () use ($app) {
    $params = $app->request->getBody();
    print_r(json_decode($params, true));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is built in to Slim but I use my own middleware to make it work.

```
class MyMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware {
  function call() {
    $body = $this->app->request->getBody();
    if (is_array($body))
      $this->app->environment()['slim.request.form_hash'] = $body;
    $this->next->call();
  }
}
```

This should be added before the `ContentTypes` middleware to ensure the correct ordering.

```
$app->add(new MyMiddleware());
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\ContentTypes());
```